Extra padding in shell title view (IOS)
When using shell title view, an extra padding space is coming below title view only in IOS.
enter image description here
Code for TitleView
<Shell.TitleView>
        <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,2*" Margin="0" Padding="0">
            <Image x:Name="ecolabLogo" AutomationId="ecolabLogoId" Source="logo.png" HeightRequest="23" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
            <Image x:Name="logOutImage" AutomationId="logOutImageId" Grid.Column="1" Source="logout.png" HeightRequest="26" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="0,0,10,0" >
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer NumberOfTapsRequired="1" Command="{Binding LogOutCommand}" />
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
        </Grid>
    </Shell.TitleView>

Can someone give me the solution to remove the extra space below shell title view (IOS) ?
Like can we do it using iOSShellRenderer, because I have tried giving padding and margins (also -ve margin) as 0 to content pages, but it is not working.

Can you help edit your post and add an image of the extra padding space which is coming below title view like you said?

Added the image, a white line below the title 'HOME'

Do you mean you want to remove the white line?

Yes, that an extra space which comes with the shell title view

You can see my answer below.

This is a known issue: Wrong underline under TitleView on iOS #6735 that is logged on Github.
As an alternative workaround, you can use Handlers to get rid of the line under TitleView.
Here's the code for your reference:
CustomShellHandler.cs:
internal class CustomShellHandler : ShellRenderer
{
    protected override IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker CreateNavBarAppearanceTracker()

       => new CustomShellNavBarAppearanceTracker(this, base.CreateNavBarAppearanceTracker());
}

CustomShellNavBarAppearanceTracker.cs:
internal class CustomShellNavBarAppearanceTracker : IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker
{

    readonly IShellContext _context;
    readonly IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker _baseTracker;

    public CustomShellNavBarAppearanceTracker(IShellContext context, IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker baseTracker)
    {
        _context = context;
        _baseTracker = baseTracker;
    }
    public void Dispose() => _baseTracker.Dispose();
    public void ResetAppearance(UINavigationController controller) => _baseTracker.ResetAppearance(controller);

    public void SetAppearance(UINavigationController controller, ShellAppearance appearance) {

        var navBar = controller.NavigationBar;

        var navigationBarAppearance = new UINavigationBarAppearance();
        navigationBarAppearance.ConfigureWithTransparentBackground();
        navigationBarAppearance.ShadowColor = UIColor.Clear;
        navigationBarAppearance.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        navigationBarAppearance.BackgroundEffect = null;
        navBar.ScrollEdgeAppearance = navBar.StandardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance;
    }
    public void SetHasShadow(UINavigationController controller, bool hasShadow) => _baseTracker.SetHasShadow(controller, hasShadow);
    public void UpdateLayout(UINavigationController controller)=>  _baseTracker.UpdateLayout(controller);
   
}

Last step, register the handlers in the MauiProgram.cs:
.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
{
#if IOS
       handlers.AddHandler<Shell, CustomShellHandler>();

#endif
}); ;



By just overiding this method only, the top line is removed.
We don't need any other properties.
internal class CustomShellHandler : ShellRenderer
{
    protected override IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker CreateNavBarAppearanceTracker()

       => new CustomShellNavBarAppearanceTracker(this, base.CreateNavBarAppearanceTracker());
}

internal class CustomShellNavBarAppearanceTracker : IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker
{
    readonly IShellContext _context;
    readonly IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker _baseTracker;

    public CustomShellNavBarAppearanceTracker(IShellContext context, IShellNavBarAppearanceTracker baseTracker)
    {
        _context = context;
        _baseTracker = baseTracker;
    }
    public void Dispose() => _baseTracker.Dispose();
    public void ResetAppearance(UINavigationController controller) => _baseTracker.ResetAppearance(controller);
    public void SetAppearance(UINavigationController controller, ShellAppearance appearance) => _baseTracker.SetAppearance(controller, appearance);
    public void SetHasShadow(UINavigationController controller, bool hasShadow) => _baseTracker.SetHasShadow(controller, hasShadow);
    public void UpdateLayout(UINavigationController controller)=>  _baseTracker.UpdateLayout(controller);
   
}

